# Multiple of linear combination of monomial characters is itself monomial

Tags: representation-theory

I was reading Ehud de Shalit's contribution to $\textit{An Introduction to the Langlands Programme}$. The following excerpt is from p. 82:

> If $\chi$ is a character which is a linear combination of monomial characters with positive rational coefficients, then some multiple $m \chi$ is monomial itself, and there are examples (e.g. when $G=\mathfrak{A}_5$), where this is impossible.

This example is included as an illustration of the fact that Brauer's theorem really is the best we can do.

I have been trying to prove this. Here is what I have come up with so far:

We have
$$
\chi = \sum_{i=1}^{h}a_i \textrm{Ind}_{H_i}^{G}(\chi_i)
$$
with $a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$, $a_i > 0$ and $\chi_i$ 1-dimensional characters.

I have been staring at this equation for a while. I suppose we should be able to find $m$ explicitly in terms of the $a_i$ and $h$, but I am at a loss.

All help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $\chi$ to be an irreducible character, or else this is clearly not true in general (take $\chi$ with degree greater than $|G|$).

Suppose an irreducible character $\chi$ is a nonnegative linear combination of monomial characters. Then each of the monomial characters that occurs with nonzero coefficient must be a multiple of $\chi$, or else some other irreducible character would occur, and the occurrences of that irreducible can't cancel, because of the nonnegativity of the coefficients.

Comment: Brilliant! But as for the second bit: Why is this impossible for $\mathfrak{A}_5$? I suspect it has something to do with the group being insoluble, but I cannot quite see how.